# Jmock match string parameter exactly

Tags: jmock

I read from Jmock's homepage about [matchers](http://www.jmock.org/matchers.html), and at the very top there was an example about string matchers. I didn't understand because, according to the example, matching a string would be as easy as writing import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*; and then using the stringContains function, but that doesn't work on my implementation.

All I want to do is

```
new Expectations() {{
  mockedType.someFunction(with(   **match string here**    ) );
}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Expectations() {{
    allowing(mockedType).someFunction("My String"); when  ... ; will ... ; then ...
}};
```

Must be working